# How can I run a postgres command after database initialisation with Django

Tags: django, postgresql

I'm trying to run some tests for a Django project and to do this Django creates a new database specific for running the tests.

In my case the main database is named 'kim' and Django creates a database 'test_kim' to run the tests on.

Since I have a `CICharField` in one of my models, I have to run this command after the database is created and before Django migrations run.

```
psql =# \c db_1
CREATE EXTENSION citext;
```

Now I'm wondering how I can run this command for the test database?

Comment: Adding a custom migration can be an option, i guess for this case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should create a migration that handles creating the extension for you. [Here are the docs on it.](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/contrib/postgres/operations/#creating-extension-using-migrations)

You would do:

```
python manage.py makemigrations <APP_NAME> --empty
```

Then in that migration import:

```
from django.contrib.postgres.operations import CITextExtension
```

and add `CITextExtension()` it to the `migrations` list. This migration should be a dependency of the migration that created the `CITextField` field.